# How can I get my website to send an email to someone from my address upon submit?

Tags: php, email

websiteI want my website to automatically generate an email to be sent to a customer when they click the submit button.

I have added the following php:

```
$subject = "Thank You";
$message = "Thank you .........";
$from = "info@mywebsite.com";
$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

The variable `$email` was defined earlier. Also I have edited my *`php.ini`* to include the following:

```
SMTP = smtp.mywebsite.com
smtp_port = 25
username = info@mywebsite.com
password = password
sendmail_from = info@mywebsites.com
```

Clearly I have not done enough. What more do I need to do?

Comment: no error, but no email is sent

Comment: You've not closed the quotes where you define `$from` - is that a typo in the code you've pasted here?

Comment: yes, that is just a typo here - the quotes are present in the actual code.

Comment: Is the missing semicolon there in your code?

Comment: yes, I'm sorry, the semicolon is there too

Comment: Are you using a Windows server, or Linux?

Comment: Is your mail server on the same server as the webserver, or is it a different server?  I also don't believe PHP by default allows for authenticated mail servers.

Comment: Does your server support mail, I tried doing this ages ago on my Mac in a local Environment before I realised I had to install postfix, the alternative is to try it via php_imap , this however requires the php_imap Extension to be installed. You can read about php_imap here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.imap.php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sending email with PHP from SMTP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-smtp-server)

Answer (score 0):

This question is duplicate with [Sending email with PHP from an SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-smtp-server)

PHP mail function has some issue with smtp. (It is not support for smtp user name and password) Use 3rd party mail library like [Swift mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/), [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer), etc...