# Is it possible to send email along with form details in php using wamp

Tags: php

Hai Friends iam trying for an online form submission .whenever i try to submit form it redirects me to MS OUTLOOK but my my form values are not included in that why?
 Is it possible or does it require ftp credentials or something. 
Give me suggestions..

Comment: http://isolani.co.uk/articles/mailto.html

Comment: `<a href="mailto:abc@example.com">abc@example.com</a>`

Answer (score -1):

It redirects you to outlook mostly because you click on `mailto:` link. You can connect to smtp server to send e-mail via php.

[Here you will find how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-smtp-server)

You don't need FTP which is file transfer protocol you need connection to SMTP which is Simple  Mail Transfer Protocol.

Also check [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

If you doesn't want to use PHP and you want send it via your client for example outlook you need do something like this:

```
<form enctype="text/plain" method="get" action="mailto:webdesign@aboutguide.com">
Your First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name"><br>
Your Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name"><br>
Comments: <textarea rows="5" cols="30" name="comments"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Code from [this page](http://webdesign.about.com/od/forms/a/aa072699mailto.htm). However, I don't recommend this solution. Connecting to SMTP via PHP is better.