# PHP mail not sending emails

Tags: php, html, email

What is the problem with this code that can't send emails for me ?

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) and (isset($_POST['email'])) and (isset($_POST['text']))) {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $text = $_POST['text'];


if (!empty($name) and !empty($email) and !empty($text)) {

$to = 'info@test34.com';
$subject = 'Testing';
$body = $text;
$headers = 'From : test@test.com';

if(mail($to, $subject,$body,$headers)) {
    echo 'Email Has bin sent.';
}
else echo "Can't Send mail";


}


}
```

I Have tried many times but the code is not working.

And the HTML is :

```
<html>
<form action="" method="POST">


Name : <br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br><br>

Email : <br>
<input type="email" name="email">
<br><br>


Message : <br>
<textarea name="text" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea> 
<Br><br>
<input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</html>
```

What should i do now ? 
Please Help me :(

Comment: I edited the OP's question, missed an indent. @ShankarDamodaran

Comment: Sidenote: `&&` has precedence over `AND`

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for edit . you mean i should use && instead of AND ?

Comment: If your `form action=""` is that, something tells me that you have your two bodies of code inside two seperate files. If that's the case, place your PHP on top and your HTML below inside a single file.

Comment: You're welcome. I usually like to use `&&` instead of `AND`, yes. @user3399133

Comment: Try [Config your machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-smtp-server) or use [SMTP class](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.smtp.php)

Comment: I think you need to try debugging a bit more. Have you verified that the issue the server is receiving the form data ok? If not fistly try simply echoing out the form data.

Comment: Thanks Fred-ii ,,, The server is ok, I have also used && instead of AND , but it's not sending again !

Comment: @user3399133 Try my suggestion!

Comment: The problem was with the space between the `From` and the colon `:` see my answer below, tested. @user3399133 I made a few adjustments also. Use exactly as posted.

Comment: Unrelated here, but open up another cloud question! I just did it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Tested** (*use exactly as posted*)

The problem seems to be caused by the space between `From` and the colon `:` in

```
$headers = 'From : test@test.com';
                ^-- right there
```

Upon testing, Email was not received till I removed the space between them.

I also added an extra conditional statement for the submit button adding `name="submit"`.

Using the following, Email was successfully sent and received.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

if (isset($_POST['name']) && (isset($_POST['email'])) && (isset($_POST['text']))) {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $text = $_POST['text'];

if (!empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($text)) {

$to = "info@test34.com";
$subject = 'Testing';
$body = $text;
$headers = 'From: test@test.com';

if(mail($to, $subject,$body,$headers)) {
    echo 'Email has been sent.';
    }
else { echo "Can't Send mail"; }

    }

    }

} // closing brace for if (isset($_POST['submit']))

?>

<html>
<form action="" method="POST">

Name : <br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br><br>

Email : <br>
<input type="email" name="email">
<br><br>

Message : <br>
<textarea name="text" rows="6" cols="30"></textarea> 
<Br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send">
</form>
</html>
```

---

**Footnotes**: If you don't want the form to reappear after the user clicks submit, you can use the following:

```
if(mail($to, $subject,$body,$headers)) {
    echo 'Email has been sent.';
echo "<br>";
echo '<a href="index.php">Click here</a> to return to our Website.';
exit; // this is the command to use in order not to show the form after
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one. change `and` to `AND`

```
if (isset($_POST['name']) AND (isset($_POST['email'])) AND (isset($_POST['text']))) {
     $name = $_POST['name'];
     $email = $_POST['email'];
     $text = $_POST['text'];


if (!empty($name) AND !empty($email) AND !empty($text)) {

$to = 'info@test34.com';
$subject = 'Testing';
$body = $text;
$headers = 'From : test@test.com';

if(mail($to, $subject,$body,$headers)) {
    echo 'Email Has bin sent.';
}
else echo "Can't Send mail";


}


}
```