# My php mail function is not working?

Tags: php, email, email-client

Ive got the following php code:

```
<?
if ($_POST['emailme']) {
$yemail = $_POST['email'];
$host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$email = "<autoreply@$host>";
if (mail('$yemail', 'This is a Subject', 'This is the body of the email', 'From: $email')) {
echo "Message sent!";
} else {
echo "Message failed sending!";
}
}
?>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION=""><INPUT TYPE='TEXT' CLASS='BOX' NAME='email' /><INPUT TYPE='SUBMIT' NAME='emailme' CLASS='SUBMITBOX' VALUE='Send!' /></FORM>
```

Any ideas why its not sending the email ? it says Message Sent but im not receiving any emails in my inbox

All help is much appreciated, thanks

PS: ive tried the following (with double quotes):

```
if (mail("$yemail", "This is a Subject", "This is the body of the email", "From:" . $email))  {
echo "Message sent!";
} else {
echo "Message failed sending!";
}
```

but still no luck

Comment: Do you know the difference between single and double quotes in PHP?

Comment: yesss,illtry with double :)

Comment: Did your `mail()` setuped?

Comment: it doesnt work with double either :(

Comment: Yes i think it is setup as it worked a while ago but its not working anymore

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
if (mail('akh40@hotmail.co.uk', 'This is a Subject', 'This is the body of the email', 'From:'. $email))
```

Comment: i hope your server supports sending main through php

Comment: If it doesnt, how would i make so it does?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently most hosting companies are dropping support for php's mail() function in favour of SMTP versions of email scripts.

See http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/protect-script-from-email-injection.shtml for an explanation of why.

Try this for an SMTP/SSL script:

```
<?php
  require_once "Mail.php";

  $from = "Sandra Sender <sender@example.com>";
  $to = "Ramona Recipient <recipient@example.com>";
  $subject = "Hi!";
  $body = "Hi,\n\nHow are you?";

  $host = "ssl://mail.example.com";
  $port = "465";
  $username = "smtp_username";
  $password = "smtp_password";

  $headers = array ('From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject);
  $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
    array ('host' => $host,
           'port' => $port,
           'auth' => true,
           'username' => $username,
           'password' => $password));

  $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

  if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
  } else {
  echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
}
?>
```

Comment: So how would i send an email?

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server if you are unsure how to set up your ini.php file for SMTP