# php mail() function doesn't return anything

Tags: php, email

I want to send mail with php mail() function from php code, this function return true but i don't receive any message I've sent is it some problem with my hMailServer in data folder it shows data like the mail was sent but I don't get nothing

Answer (score 0):

You need an SMTP server to send mail.
this post will probably help you. 
[PHP mail() function returns true, but doesn't send mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23857539/php-mail-function-returns-true-but-doesnt-send-mail)

Comment: I have it hMailServer and I set in php.ini SMTP=localhost and port=25, Is it problem with configuration of hMailServer because I made doman and set localhost name on =localhost