# How do I use ssmtp for sending mail in php?

Tags: php, ubuntu, ssmtp

I am using Ubuntu 19.10.
I have just installed `ssmtp` and reconfigured the file `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` as given in https://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-with-gmail-and-ssmtp/
So my **/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf** looks like -

```
# Make this empty to disable rewriting.
root=demo@gmail.com

# The place where the mail goes. The actual machine name is required no 
# MX records are consulted. Commonly mailhosts are named mail.domain.com
mailhub=smtp.gmail.com:587
# Where will the mail seem to come from?
#rewriteDomain=

# The full hostname
hostname=127.0.1.1:80
UseSTARTTLS=YES
AuthUser=demo@gmail.com
AuthPass=123456

# Are users allowed to set their own From: address?
# YES - Allow the user to specify their own From: address
# NO - Use the system generated From: address
FromLineOverride=YES
```

Mail path in ***php.ini***
`sendmail_path    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i`

and custom php script ***send_mail.php*** for send mail -

```
<?php
  // the message
  $msg = 'Testing for send mail in Linux';
  // send email
  $send = mail('demo@gmail.com','My subject',$msg);
  echo $send ?  'MAIL SENT' : 'MAIL NOT SENT';
?>
```

**OUTPUT when running through browser**
MAIL NOT SENT 
**OUTPUT when running through terminal (*php send_mail.php*)**
sendmail:  (127.0.1.1:80)
MAIL NOT SENT
*Help me please !*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send email with SMTP in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909348/how-to-send-email-with-smtp-in-php)

Comment: I don't want to use PHPMailer because [send mail using ssmtp](https://www.nixtutor.com/linux/send-mail-with-gmail-and-ssmtp/) link didn't use PHPMailer and they are able to send mails through localhost without PHPMailer

Comment: [There is usually a different `php.ini` for php/www and php-cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3057110/where-can-i-find-the-php-ini-for-php-cli), have you updated both?

Comment: I just used PHPMailer [How to send email with SMTP in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909348/how-to-send-email-with-smtp-in-php) and i write a line `require './src/PHPMailer.php'` in my custom send_mail.php file. But it is giving me error `Uncaught Error: Class 'PHPMailer' not found`

Comment: Alright.. I used PHPMailer and i am getting long error acronym as  : `SMTP Error: Could not authenticate. Username and Password not accepted`

Comment: Did you read my comment? Have you checked your php-cli php.ini?

Comment: @Don'tPanic I have checked. I have updated both but still I am getting same problem.