# email sending code is not working

Tags: php

i am tryind to send an email using my php program

here is my code

```
  $to = "sunilchhimpa92@gmail.com";
  $subject = "This is subject";
  $message = "This is simple text message.";
  $header = "sunilchhimpa92@yahoo.com \r\n";
 $mail_send = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
  echo $to. $subject.$message.$header;
  var_dump($mail_send);
  if( $mail_send == true )  
  {
    echo "Message sent successfully...";
  }
   else
   {
     echo "Message could not be sent...";
   }
```

here var_dump($mail_send) returning false.

and echo Message could not be sent...

what is the problem with my code

is password of sender mail  is required ?

how can i do that ?

Comment: That is not a valid header.

Comment: `$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();` got it `mail php manual`

Comment: if you are using it from local server,you can't send email from localhost until you configure SMTP

Comment: i have tried this also        $headers = "From: sunilchhimpa92@yahoo.com\r\nReply-To: sunilchhimpa92@yahoo.com";

Comment: yes i am doing it from local server. how to configure SMTP

Comment: read this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server i think you might find your answer there

Comment: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page?rq=1>

Answer (score 0):

You can check this in server its working.

```
$admin_to   = 'bhavesh930@gmail.com';
$a_subject  = 'Subject';
$a_from     = 'someone@gmail.com';
$fromcc     = 'someone@gmail.com';      //for multiple user if required than only          

$a_headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$a_headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$a_headers .= "From:".$a_from."\r\n";

$a_headers .= "Bcc: ".$fromcc."\r\n";

$a_message= "<html>
   <body>
        <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>

    <tr>
        <td>Message</td>
    </tr>

        </table>
    </body>
   </html>";

 $sendmail =  @mail($a_to,$a_subject,$a_message,$a_headers);
```