# How does Mail PHP work?

Tags: php, email

I stumbled on the following script today for sending an e-mail using PHPMail.

```
<?php
    $to = "some_address@domain.com";
    $subject = "Test mail";
    $message = "Hello! This is a simple email message.";
    $from = "my_address@domain.com";
    $headers = "From:" . $from;
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "Mail Sent.";
?>
```

Above can be runnable through `php mail.php` and instantly you'll get an e-mail sent to `$to` from `$from` despite not needing to set outgoing/ingoing servers out.

It really intrigued me, since my CMS uses an SMTP outgoing server (well, same way Mail PHP does), which I need to set up with my Outlook SMTP username and password - some sort of verification.

However, about Mail PHP just.. sends an e-mail. To the address you set it as. From the address you set it as.

Looking at [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) it does not really reveal how it works. Does Mail PHP not have any issues with spamming since anyone can send anyone anything anytime programmatically without verification of the `from` identity?

EDIT:

It's rather funny the people in the comments were talking about the POTUS, since I had the exact thing in mind:

[image]

It *did* land in my junk folder, but I'm sure it isn't hard to make this look convincing enough and still be considered `"oh damn spam filter lost my e-mail!"`

Comment: if the From is overwritten, and it's not as what your provider gives you, those mails are usually will lands in spam folder.

Comment: The last part of your question answers it. That's one of the many reasons you shouldn't rely on PHP's mail function

Comment: Try looking at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14456761/1857053 and using PHPmailer

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, or mail. That's just the way SMTP works. I can trivially forge an email to anyone with `From: president@whitehouse.gov`. Whether the receiving server will accept it is another matter, but SENDING forged emails has never been "hard"

Comment: Wait, so I wasn't contacted by the president @MarcB ?

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ Check edit. I think the POTUS wants to talk to me.

Comment: @theGreenCabbage You're one lucky cabbage!

Comment: Proper headers are very important to many mail servers or clients in order to avoid ending up as "spam" or at "junk" folder... And as mentioned before, try PHPMailer... its a very helpful class in many cases... https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: @captaintheo oh I know about PHPMailer. I just found the prospecting of being able to forge "from" quite intriguing. Are you telling me if.. Not that I will do it or anything.. But if my headers are well-crafted (though I still unfortunately don't have access to the whitehouse.gov's SMTP credentials) enough, I could land on the non-junk folder?

Comment: @MarcB I've seen much less convincing emails from official domains land in my junk folder before (that I had to say it wasn't junk).

Comment: @theGreenCabbage: youdon't have to involve whitehouse.gov's mail servers AT ALL to forge an email. you can use your own ISP or your own isntalled-at-home smtp server. The only difference between a real presidential email and the one you forge would be the smtp server path that shows up in the mail's headers. (ignoring DKIM and other anti-spam systems)

Comment: @theGreenCabbage I am telling you that the better the headers are, the more chances you get to achieve a successful delivery. Of course headers is NOT the only factor to that. (otherwise companies offering smtp services would be bankrupt by now!)  And yes, you could try to fake a third party domain name, but is up to the recipient server to drop your message since (for example) your IP will not have a legit spf record bound to the NS record of that domain. Lastly, please note that in my previous comment, I did not refer at all to forging the "from" header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `mail` function uses the settings from php.ini. The details of this configuration can be found in [Mail Runtime Configuration](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php).

The defaults can be set in php.ini, although you can override them using [`ini_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

I bet you sent the mail from a PHP script on a hosted server. That server probably has SMTP settings configured beforehand. If you would try this locally on a WAMP/LAMP server, you would have to do this configuration yourself, since PHP cannot read your Outlook/WhateverMailclient settings.

As stated in the comments, you can specify the sender/from address yourself. SMTP doesn't require this to be the actual sender domain, so that's why this works. The missing link is the pre-configured SMTP server of your host.

Some relay servers do check for this, and your mail might be blocked or sent to a junk mail folder. You can however configure this in your DNS to indicate that `<Your server's IP>` is indeed allowed to send email for `<yourdomain>`. For more information about that subject, you might want to read [this question on ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/24943/reverse-dns-how-to-correctly-configure-for-smtp-delivery).

Comment: I simply ran my script via `php mail.php`. Does having Apache installed make a difference?

Comment: I think not. The configuration is in php.ini, and should also work when PHP is called from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

It uses the smtp protocol or send_mail, you can even configure what php should use to send mails in php.ini. It can send e-mail but the e-mail will end-up in your spam filter take a look to DKIM and SPF records for more information