# What are the steps involved in setting up a mail server to enable a contact form to be fully functional?

Tags: php, html, forms, email, smtp

I understand how to set up the form itself in HTML and PHP, but what are the ensuing steps involved that lead to a fully functional contact form? I have no experience setting up SMTP servers - are they an additional cost when using a hosting provider like godaddy or rackspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the php mail() function. It is configure on many hosting provider to use their SMTP server.  [see more here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21293568/3087164)

If you need to configure your own SMTP, you should use a php library like PHPmailer or Swiftmailer.

Answer (score 1):

When using a hosting provider like GoDaddy, the mail servers you're talking about are already hosted by the hosting provider.

Most hosting providers will allow you to create your own mail accounts as well when linking your domain to the web host.

All you'll have to do is create your contact form and voila!