# How Can I Send Mail From localhost

Tags: php

I Cant send Mail From Localhost.
I Use Xampp And My php.ini  And sendmail.ini File Are Proper Configured

What Can I Do Now?

Comment: Refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965376/how-to-configure-xampp-to-send-mail-from-localhost . Please search properly before asking.

Comment: I Search This Tropic Before

Comment: then can you provide with a sample code ?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send mail from localhost using `mail` function. you have to use `SMTP` in order to send email.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server) for how to use SMTP to send email.

Comment: Hey Brother,  Thank's For Your Answer ..

Comment: I Am Use SMTP Also But Mail Dose not send ...

Comment: Follow the above link I mentioned in my answer. There are lot of ways mentioned there that you can use to send email through SMTP.

Comment: Can you explain that further? Why should that not be possible? If there is a proper mail server behind your localhost, there should not be any problems

Answer (score 1):

**If you only need to test your mail function without being connected to the internet**, you should use [Papercut](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut), this simple application to test send mail. You don't need to configure anything.

Just run it and try test send mail.

sendmail.php

```
<?php
     $to = "sampleperson@example.com";
     $subject = "My Subject";
     $txt = "My sample msg.";
     $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
     "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";

     mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);
?>
```

You will get this.
[Papercut Inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvwBm.png)

Download Papercut [here](https://github.com/ChangemakerStudios/Papercut/releases)