# Issues with HTML PHP Mailer

Tags: php, html, email

i I've been trying to get a .php that works with this HTML code for my website (template), I tried using my old .php from my old website and changing the details but that sadly lead to no avail.

I am clueless when it comes to .php and would really appreciate your help!

What would my .php have to contain?

```
<form action="#" id="contact-form">
    <div id="success"></div>
    <ul>
    <li class="input-name">
        <input type="text" id="name" class="required" placeholder="Name">
    </li> <!-- END input-name -->
    <li class="input-email">
        <input type="text" id="email" class="email" placeholder="Email Address">
    </li> <!-- END input-name -->
    <li class="input-subject">
        <input type="text" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
    </li> <!-- END input-name -->
    <li class="input-subject">
        <textarea rows="7" cols="50" id="message" class="required" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </li> <!-- END input-name -->
    </ul> <!-- END #contact -->
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg pull-right">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you want to do with this code? there is no action for form!!!

Comment: What exactly is not working? Could you post some errors? The HTML itself isn't much of a help.

Comment: the .php file is named "contactForm.php" and it only contained 

<?php

// Insert your SMTP code or mail() function here.
// You can take a look at this if you need instructions: 
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server

?>

but I couldn't make sense of the link that was on the .php form. (sorry)

Comment: Your action refers to the same page at the moment, is this where your mail function is placed?

Comment: It won't let me post my .php file contents, how come?

Comment: hey @JackEvans I commented on your question

Answer (score 1):

if you are not using ajax then write php file name in form action attribute currently there is #. then you php file will be called.

Answer (score 1):

Change the below code

```
<form action="#" id="contact-form">
```

to

```
<form action="mailer.php" method="post" id="contact-form">
```

hope this will help.

Comment: My old .php for my old website looked like this was called "mailer.php" so I should change "name" to "mailer yes?

Comment: yes that's right...check my edited answer...If it works please vote my answer.

Comment: I think it's my .php file that is the issue as the form isn't working still! I can't post my .php contents as it won't let me, how can I get around this?

Comment: @JackEvans :- use method="post" inside form...check my edited answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the in `action="#"` the php file. example: `action="contactForm.php"`. That's how the HTML code knows where to send the parameters.

Also, make sure your server supports the 'mail' function.

AND!

I have a good standard example for you of a well written mailing php file that I used. So you can check yourself for syntax issues.

```
<?php 
require_once "Mail.php";

        if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

            $email = $_POST['email'];       //this is how you get your variables from the HTML file. 'edit' is the id of the element. 
            $email_to = "yourEmail@example.com";

            $host = "ssl://smtp.gmail.com:465";  //use your email host - this example is gmail based. (you can search for your own email host via google). 
            $username = 'username@example.pro';
            $password = 'yourPass';

            $email_subject = "You have a new email from $email via example.com website";
            $message = $_POST['text']; 

            $headers = array ('From' => $email, 'To' => $email_to,'Subject' => $email_subject);
            $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
              array ('host' => $host,
                'auth' => true,
                'username' => $username,
                'password' => $password));

            $mail = $smtp->send($email_to, $headers, $message);

            if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
              echo($mail->getMessage());
            } else {
              echo("Message successfully sent!\n");
            }

        }
```

In case of sending emails with ajax - it's an other thing.. and I can help you with that too.