# PHP mail() function is working on one server and not on other

Tags: php, email

I am sending mail using mail function in php, however this function is working on one server but when I copied files to another server they are not working.

I am not able to figure out the error.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
// Fetching Values from URL.
$name = $_POST['name1'];
$cname = $_POST['cname1'];
$email = $_POST['email1'];
$cnumber = $_POST['cnumber1'];

$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); // Sanitizing E-mail.

// After sanitization Validation is performed
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

$subject = 'Something here..';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set.
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: info@something.com'. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$template = '<div style="padding:50px; color:#696969;"><b>Hello there,    Someone just show their interest in Free Cloud Consultation Session.<br/>Please see details below:<br><br/>'
. '<b>Name:</b> ' . $name . '<br/>'
. '<b>Company Name:</b> ' . $cname . '<br/>'
. '<b>Email:</b> ' . $email . '<br/>'
. '<b>Contact Number:</b> ' . $cnumber . '<br/></div>';
$sendmessage = "<div style=\"background-color:#F8F8F8; color:white;\">" .      $template . "</div>";

// Message lines should not exceed 70 characters (PHP rule), so wrap it.
$sendmessage = wordwrap($sendmessage, 70);

// Send mail by PHP Mail Function.
mail("dm2@e-pspl.com", $subject, $sendmessage, $headers);// dm2@e-pspl.com

/* Sending message to user who filled form */
$headers1 = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers1 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers1 .= 'From: adfa@da.com'. "\r\n"; // Sender's Email
$subject1 = 'Thanks for signing up for Cloud Consultation session';
$template1 = '<div style="padding:50px; color:#696969;"><b>Hey,<br><br>
Some message<br><br>
Regards,<br>
Some company</div>';
$sendmessage1 = "<div style=\"background-color:#F8F8F8; color:white;\">" . $template1 . "</div>";
$sendmessage1 = wordwrap($sendmessage1, 70);
mail($email, $subject1, $sendmessage1, $headers1);
}
?>
```

Comment: Despite the problem of the question, I suggest you to avoid using php built-in mail function, and use a proper SMTP.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server