# PHP - SMTP configuration without php.ini

Tags: php, email, smtp

I am using mail() to send emails in my php application. Since I do not have access to my hosting server settings ( php.ini ), is it possible to configure the SMTP settings from my application ? So far I have found this approach

```
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp', array(
            'host' => 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com',
            'port' => '465',
            'auth' => true,
            'username' => 'your@gmail.com', //your gmail account
            'password' => 'snip' // your password
    ));
```

but once I am not sure how to include this Mail class and second I need to do this everywhere I send mails in the app so seems not good for me.

Comment: What are you using for your mailing? Is it just the standard mail function? And you made that class and method?

Comment: If so, look at PHPMailer: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: yes, I`m using the standard mail function, the code above is what I found for alternative to setup manually the smtp settings

Comment: is there any way to easily configure the smtp settings for the standard mail function ?

Comment: If you can figure that out, let me know. It's better to use what's readily available than to try to reinvent the wheel. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14456673/1524676

Comment: Can I create custom php.ini file in my website root dir and add there only the [mail function] settings ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. You could use ini_set() though: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php

Answer (score 0):

[The PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) says you can set everything except the path to the `sendmail` binary in your directory-local `.htaccess` files. Your sample code appears to use the PEAR::Mail extension, which may not be available on your system.