# PHP Contact form no longer working after changing DNS

Tags: php, email, web, dns, contacts

I had my website hosting its own DNS records and mail accounts through channel. However, I migrated the email hosting over to fastmail and now have the DNS hosted through them and have A records pointing to my web hosting server IP.

Since changing to this setup, my contact form on my homepage is broken. I will attach the php code.

```
 <?php
// Check for empty fields
if(empty($_POST['name'])        ||
   empty($_POST['email'])       ||
   empty($_POST['phone'])       ||
   empty($_POST['message']) ||
   !filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
   {
    echo "No arguments Provided!";
    return false;
   }

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email_address = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

// Create the email and send the message
$to = 'i did put my real email here.'; // Add your email address inbetween the '' replacing yourname@yourdomain.com - This is where the form will send a message to.
$email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n"."Here are the details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nPhone: $phone\n\nMessage:\n$message";
$headers = "From: noreply@yourdomain.com\n"; // This is the email address the generated message will be from. We recommend using something like noreply@yourdomain.com.
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email_address"; 
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
return true;            
?>
```

The HTML code:

```
<form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Name</label>
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Email Address</label>
                                <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Phone Number</label>
                                <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row control-group">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                                <label>Message</label>
                                <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <div id="success"></div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="form-group col-xs-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

I'm thinking it must not be sending mail properly now or something from the web host side. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: My web host suggested using SMTP but I don't know what they mean.

Comment: does sending a simple e-mail to the target address from your computer actually work ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like mail is not enabled. If they want you to use SMTP, they probably don't allow their webservers to send email.

You could use PHPMailer to use another smtp-server, see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server).

Change the smtp-server to the one you can use (ask your provider).