# How to send mail by PHP

Tags: php, sendmail

I have a PHP simple code which supposed to send an email, but it seems it does not work since I have never received any mail.
Well I have a free free host and domain with CPanel that I have a Webmail feature there, I can send email through that to wherever I want (Yahoomail, Gmail, ..).
I really do not know how to solve it.
Here is my php code:

```
$to = 'sample@yahoo.com'; 
$subject = 'the subject'; 
$message = 'hello'; 
$headers = 'From: sample@sample.com' . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: sample@sample.com' . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion(); 
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);`
```

My sendmail_path `/usr/local/bin/phpsendmail`, Path to sendmail `/usr/local/bin/phpsendmail`, SMTP localhost, smtp_port 25

Comment: I think you can find a fix here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server

Answer (score -1):

Try this ...

    `$to = "somebody@example.com";
    $subject = "My subject";
    $txt = "Hello world!";
    $headers = "From: webmaster@example.com" . "\r\n" .
    "CC: somebodyelse@example.com";
    mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers);`