# Sending mails using gmail app

Tags: php, gmail-api

Is it possible to send mail using PHP, via google, like we use the mandrill api? I have a server with no mail support and want to send emails from the website hosted in it. Can i use Gmail API for this?

We have a google app paid account and can we add a new domain to it and use the google mail API?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Look into [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). You can enter your google apps credentials to send an email from gmail.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google SMTP.

> You have the option of having Google store and index the emails you
>   send via its SMTP server, so all your sent emails will be searchable
>   and backed-up on Google's servers. If you elect to use your Gmail or
>   Google Apps account for your incoming email as well, you'll have all
>   your email in one convenient place. Also, since Google's SMTP server
>   does not use Port 25, you'll reduce the probability that an ISP might
>   block your email or flag it as SPAM.

[Here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-google-s-smtp-server) is the article.

Use PHP Mailer extension to drive your emails.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456761/4185234) answer gives you an insight on how to use the PHP Mailer on external SMTP.