# use php mail function to send email via ssmpt

Tags: php, email, nginx, sendmail, smpp

So I have installed ssmpt and successfully tested email send using ssmpt.

Now the problem is, php mail function fails to send email.
I have tried, both the following configuration in php.ini

```
sendmail_path = sendmail -t -i
or
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmpt -t
or
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t
```

my simple php file is as follows:

```
<?php
$to = "to@gmail.com";
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>HTML email</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
    </body>
    </html>";

// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";


mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
?>
```

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: Do you have a login? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server

Comment: Yes, the script works fine when is run via terminal as php script.php but, when executed from browser, it is not sending email

Comment: Normally CLI and CGI use different php.ini files. Did you change both?

Comment: I added the sendmail_path to fpm/php.ini, I'm using nginx