# Silex and HTTPS

Tags: php, https, twig, silex

I have a problem with configure Silex and HTTPS.
I added my Silex application to the https server. Login module is ok, but redirection is doesn't works. Website [mypage.com](https://mypage.com/delivery) works, but all created paths (url function in twig) returns url with http (ex. http://mypage.com/delivery). I tried the requireHttps function, but then I get the error "loop redirect". How to configure silex for url to return url from https?

.htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
```

Example twig file:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="menu_li text-center data-url="{{ url('first') }}">First</li>
    <li class="menu_li text-center data-url="{{ url('second')}}">Second</li>
</ul>
```

Example route (doesn't work):

```
$app->get('/first', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
   return 'FIRST';
})
->bind('first')
->requireHttps();
```

Comment: Could you try and force rewrite in your .htaccess? This seems like a good example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server

Comment: Without single line of code, you can't get any answer :-*)*