# Send sms using mail function in php

Tags: php, sms-gateway

Someone help me on how to send sms using mail function
this is my php code:

```
   <?php
   $to = "xxxxxxxxxxx@smart.mms.ph";
   $from = "xxxxxxxx@gmail.com";
   $message = "sample";
   $header = "From: $from\n";
   mail($to,'',$message,$header);
   ?>
```

after i test the code i got some error:
Says: **Warning**: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\sample-sms\send.php on line 6

i also put my email in mail function in my php.ini

```
      SMTP=localhost
      smtp_port=25
      sendmail_from = xxxxxxxx@gmail.com
```

Comment: do you have a mailserver installed?

Comment: In my understanding, sms is a paid services from 3rd party, you cant send sms directly from your server...

Comment: i have installed hmailserver in my local

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server