# adding smtp authentication to PHP

Tags: php, smtp-auth

I'm trying to send an php mail in a website. I want to add smtp authentication. Below is the php code for send email. How can I add smtp authentication to the below script. Is there any installer I have to download. Please help me with the simplest way to implement this. the smtp details that I have are $host, $username, $password

```
<?php
if(!$_POST) exit;
function isEmail($email) {
    return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|me|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i",$email));
}
if (!defined("PHP_EOL")) define("PHP_EOL", "\r\n");
$name     = $_POST['name'];
$email    = $_POST['email']; 
$comments = $_POST['comments'];
$verify   = $_POST['verify'];
if(trim($email) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">enter a valid email address.</div>';
    exit();
} else if(!isEmail($email)) {
    echo '<div class="error_message">invalid e-mail address, try again.</div>';
    exit();
}
if(trim($comments) == '') {
    echo '<div class="error_message">enter your message.</div>';
    exit();
}
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}
$address = "example@example.com";
$e_subject = 'You\'ve been contacted by ' . $name . '.';
$e_body = "You have been contacted by $name, their message is as follows." . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_content = "\"$comments\"" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
$e_reply = "You can contact $name via email, $email";
$msg = wordwrap( $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply, 70 );
$headers = "From: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8" . PHP_EOL;
$headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable" . PHP_EOL;
if(mail($address, $e_subject, $msg, $headers)) {
    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h4 class='highlight'>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</h4>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";
} else {
    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending email with PHP from an SMTP server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server)

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use PHPMailer from https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer
[Authentication Sample](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/smtp.phps)

Download or install with Composer

Add these code at beginning of your file

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```

Then to send your email

```
...
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())
{
    $comments = stripslashes($comments);
}
$e_body    = "You have been contacted by {$name}, their message is as follows.\r\n\r\n";
$e_content = "\"{$comments}\"\r\n\r\n";
$e_reply   = "You can contact $name via email, $email";


$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host     = "localhost";
$mail->Port     = 25;
$mail->From     = "from@email.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "SMTP_username";
$mail->Password = "SMTP_password";
$mail->setFrom($email, $name);
$mail->addReplyTo($email, $name);
$mail->addAddress("to@email.com");
$mail->Subject = "You've been contacted by {$name}.";
$mail->setWordWrap(70);
$mail->Body = $e_body . $e_content . $e_reply;
$mail->isHTML(false);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';

if ($mail->send())
{
    echo "<fieldset>";
    echo "<div id='success_page'>";
    echo "<h4 class='highlight'>Thank you <strong>$name</strong>, your message has been submitted to us.</h4>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</fieldset>";
}
else
{
    echo 'ERROR!';
}
```

Comment: `need` is such a big word here

Comment: No worries, I'd too would advice using a library like `PHPMailer` over sending mails manualy