# how do I get PHP to send data to gmail?

Tags: php, variables, gmail

I would like to create a php script that sends data to Gmail whenever someone makes a purchase. I'm only looking to send  couple variables, is there any way to do this?

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST["firstname"];
$lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
$email = $_POST['emailaddress'];

// Send data to Gmail
?????

?>
```

If there's not a way to do this through PHP, what would be the best way? If Gmail is the best service to use for this, What would be the be third-party service?

I'm open to any suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to send a mail?

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server

if you have a gmail account you can use the google smtp service https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en

Comment: You can send mails using php `mail()` function or with smtp service with `PhpMailer`. I have made a video on how to send with PHP mail: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_8PISnkumHI