# HTML5 Email form with PHP not sending E-mails

Tags: php, html, forms, email

I'm following [this tutorial](https://1stwebdesigner.com/php-contact-form-html/), and I can't get it to work.

I even copied the finished example (and put my E-mail in the recipient section) and it still doesn't work as I never receive an E-mail.

My environment:

- Apache 2.4.29
- PHP 7.2
- Ubuntu 18.04 64-bit.

Comment: What is your email service? Did you setup the email server on your local server at all?

Comment: The recipient E-mail is Yahoo. The tutorial makes no mention of an E-mail server, I have not set one up.

Comment: have you tried to debug?

Comment: NMoeini is on the correct track here your problem is almost certainly you don't have a valid email smtp setup to handle sending email. Go to Sendgrid and sign up for free, follow their toutorial. You want to use a 3rd party or your emails probably will be in the spam folder or not work at all.

Comment: The debugger in Firefox says 200 OK for the POST request my HTML5 form submits. @rifi2k Why is this not mentioned in any of the tutorials online? Very frustrating.

Comment: I'm telling you do what I said and use the API method if possible. Your 200 just means your front end is good your back end is the issue

Comment: When I get home I'll link you to a good explaination of how to do what you want

Comment: So you need an email server up and running on your environment (your local machine). Follow this [gist](https://gist.github.com/raelgc/6031274) if you want.

Comment: What MTA are you using? What do the logs (mail.log, syslog) show?

Comment: I don't know what an MTA is. I tried following [the tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456761/4441547) that @damnguy linked and it did not work. I tried setting up PHPMailer with SendGrid as rifi2k suggested, I copied the code and added the login details, yet it does not work.

Comment: I agree with damnguy this is probably asked and answered multiple times also a Google search for the title of the linked duplicate topic will yield you a ton of actionable ways to go about solving this. This link explains MTA as well https://blog.edmdesigner.com/sending-email-with-php/ If you continue to have issues I would recommend finding a hosting company offering fully managed Wordpress hosting I guarantee you can get into a site which will be plug and play for under $7 a month.