# How to stop email in spam

Tags: php, email, mysqli

I create Html content send through email,
but email goes in the spam folder;
So how to solve this, please help me.

I read that question but this not help me
Thanks advanced,

```
<?php 
 $to1 = 'test@gmail.com, toganeshwagh@gmail.com';
 $subject = 'Tester subject.'; 

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set

$headers .= "Reply-To: The Sender <sender@sender.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Return-Path: The Sender <sender@sender.com>\r\n"; 
$headers .= "From: test@test.in" ."\r\n" .
$headers .= "Organization: Sender Organization\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Priority: 3\r\n";
$headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP". phpversion() ."\r\n" ;

?>
```

Comment: Use [SMTP](https://www.formget.com/send-email-via-gmail-smtp-server-in-php/)

Comment: for easy way use `SMTP` using [`phpmailer`](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: check This They providing all infoemation
--
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14456761/10694450

Comment: @ZainFarooq : I tried but not solve