# Setting up SMTP mailing with PHP 7.2 in 2020 - PHP Mailing in 2020

Tags: php, email, smtp

I want to know how I can set up automatic SMTP mailing system in php 7.2 in 2020.
I know about `mail()` function but that comes after the initial set up.

I have seen the other questions on stackoverflow about it, but I am posting this question bc I only found only **outdated** questions from like **2011** or **2012** and PHP has changed **a lot** from that time from security aspect and other aspects.

Here is what I tried:

> From what I found I should be changing `ini_set()` in `php.ini` file but there are none of `ini_set()` functions there. What I did is I changed `smtp` to `smtp=my-mail-server-of-choice-here` and `smtp_port` to `smtp_port=587` like I was told to.

> Also, I should be updating `sendmail.ini` in `sendmail` folder but (guess what) **`sendmail folder` doesn't exist** -> that also means `sendmail.exe` and `sendmail.ini` **also don't exist**

I am also getting this error `mail(): SMTP server response: 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first`

This is the file:

```
$to = 'my-users-mail@some-random.mail';
$subject = "HTML email";

$message = "Hi Bob!";

$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0"."\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8"."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: my-mail@gmail.com'."\r\n";

mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

which (from what I read) should be fixable from `ini_set()` which **doesn't exist** anywhere in `php.ini` file - I guess that bc only outdated solutions are available

What is the **modern** standard, php 7.2, way of doing this that's actually going to work and be **safe**?

BTW I am using `XAMPP v3.2.4` (I will be moving to `WAMPP` in production) on `localhost` and I am using `gmail` as my mail service

Comment: Do you *need* to use mail()? If not there's an answer updated on Aug 3rd here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server Another option being: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer returned from a quick google search. I'd answer, but not sure one is needed? I do appreciate you looking for a modern solution though

Comment: I don't need to use mail(). I will check this out and I will let u know. Thanks! Also I don't really want to use extensions, classes and what not for the simple 'thank u for joining our website' mail. I was looking for simple solution.

Comment: I get that... if you want to send straight from your server: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-on-ubuntu-14-04 and/or https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-postfix-as-a-send-only-smtp-server-on-ubuntu-16-04 - obviously you'll have to adapt to a wamp(not sure where xamp is set up for testing) environment or find another tutorial, but incase these are helpful. If you're strictly windows based there are alternatives

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I am using windows (wamp stack) and the link you sent is for ubuntu os

Comment: Gotcha, https://alternativeto.net/software/postfix/?platform=windows - the site is a good one to keep around in general

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will try that and when I will let u know if I find a way. I will also write an answer to this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bad idea of "modern" thinking. The new way of doing things is actually using extensions, frameworks etc etc... - **reusable code** is the word in this fast expanding it world

Back in like '90s or '80s people didn't have the internet so widely available or available at all and if you wanted to (lets say) make connection between two computers (think NASA or something) you would have to write your own protocols (POP or IMAP) from scratch and spend weeks or even months in programming.

Now its 2020. and we have **a lot** of reusable code widely available, repositories, open-source software etc... you get the picture

Sure you can write you own authentication in php in like a week or you can simply download

> Net_Socket (i have 1.2.2) -> https://pear.php.net/package/Net_Socket/download/
> Net_SMTP (i have 1.9.2) -> https://pear.php.net/package/Net_SMTP/download/
> Mail_extension (I have version 1.4.1) -> https://pear.php.net/package/Mail/download/

extract everything with 7-zip and structure it like this

your main folder

```
.Mail-1.4.1
    >Mail.php
    >Mail
        > some default files(dont touch these)
        > Net(here you paste files from Net_SMTP and Net_Socket - they should be named SMTP.php and Socket.php)

. sendmail.php
```

In sendmail.php you write this:

```
//Make sure you made your folder/file structure like you should
require_once "./Mail-1.4.1/Mail.php";

$host = "your-mail-server-of-choice-here";
$port = "465";
$username = "your mail or username";
$password = "your password";

//setting up smtp connection
$smtp = Mail::factory(
    'smtp',
    array (
        'host' => $host,
        'port' => $port,
        //you don't need this if u are using mail server that doesn't need authentication
        'auth' => true,
        'username' => $username,
        'password' => $password
    )
);

$from = "your-mail-here";
$to = "recepient-mail-here";
$subject = "Ay bro!";
$body = "Your message here!";

$headers = array (
    'From' => $from,
    'To' => $to,
    'Subject' => $subject
);

$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {
    exit( "Error happened :( -->".$mail->getMessage() );
}
```

That was easy right? If we went your way, you would spend **a lot** of time and tears(yes tears) on making all of these connections and stuff and make it safe etc etc. I hope you are happy with this results!

Comment: @JonNezbit Thans a lot! What I also needed to do is reset everything I changed in `php.ini` and it worked finally! Upvoted and make an accepted answer to my question!