# Best way to send form data/values from a html to an email for a beginner?

Tags: php, html

So I'm building a small website and i need to create a html form where the values would be sent to my client's email.

The form code:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="POST" action="form-to-email.php" role="form">
        <div class="messages"></div>
        <div class="controls">
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_name">Name *</label>
                                        <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Name *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                                        <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your Email *" required="required" data-error="Email is required.">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_social">Other Socials</label>
                                        <input id="form_social" type="text" name="other_socials" class="form-control">
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_need">Services</label>
                                        <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example" name="services">
                                                <option selected>Select a Service</option>
                                                <option value="Live2D Vtuber Rigging">Live2D Vtuber Rigging</option>
                                                <option value="Animation">Animation</option>
                                                <option value="Illustration">Illustration</option>
                                                <option value="Graphics">Graphics</option>
                                                <option value="Others">Others</option>
                                                <option value="General Enquiry">General Enquiry</option>
                                        </select>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                                        <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please, leave us a message."></textarea>
                                        <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
                        </div>
                </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

I'm using basic HTML/JS and php.

I've tried this [example](https://html.form.guide/email-form/php-form-to-email/) but I have an error 405 which I assume from another answer is due to me using a localhost (using MAMP localhost).

Friend suggested using Google smtp but i'm totally lost as i'm a beginner to frontend, so i'm not sure where to start.

I did some resaerch and there was suggestion to use PHPmailer but i'm not even sure how to intergrate it with my code?

Any suggestions on where to start off?

Comment: You can get the answer here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14456673/sending-email-with-php-from-an-smtp-server

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send email using the GMail SMTP server from a PHP page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/712392/send-email-using-the-gmail-smtp-server-from-a-php-page)

Answer (score 0):

In your php file write it-

```
<?php
    $userName = $_POST['name'];
    $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
    $otherSocials= $_POST['other_socials'];
    $services= $_POST['services'];

    $to = "info@email.com"; // Add your client email addresss
    $body = "";

    $body .= "Name: ".$userName. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Email: ".$userEmail. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Other Socials: ".$otherSocials. "\r\n";
    $body .= "Services: ".$services. "\r\n";

    if(mail($to,$messageSubject,$body)){
        echo "Email Sent Successfully!";
    } else{
        echo "Sorry, something went wrong";
    }
?>
```

that's it.